# How can I add multiple paths to a Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I tried so many ways but could not find a way to add at least four paths to the Firestore.

My JSON tree is as follows:

`ActiveTrades -> Userid -> autogeneratedId -> data fields`

I've tried as follows:

```
var ref = firebase.firestore();
var addOrder = ref.collection("ActiveTrades").doc(userId).add({
 orderId: 1234
});

var ref = firebase.firestore();
var addOrder = ref.doc("ActiveTrades/"+userid).add({
 orderId: 1234
});
```

Comment: yes, it a user's uid

Comment: yes it says doc and add dont go together

Comment: i know but i wanted to generate a unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem that you have, is that you can only add a document to a collection.  You are trying to add a document to another document.  Take a look at the [Cloud Firestore Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) documentation for a better understanding.

You need to structure your data with one of the following methods:
`/ActiveTrades/{userId}/orders/{orderId}`
or
`/ActiveTrades/{orderId}`

If you want to add an auto Id, there are 2 ways of doing this...

### Create an auto ID and then set it

```
var ref = firebase.firestore();
var orderRef = ref.collection("ActiveTrades").doc(userId).collection("orders").doc();
console.log("The new order ID is", orderRef.id);
var addOrder = orderRef.set({
 orderId: 1234
});
```

### Create a new document and then get the ID

```
var ref = firebase.firestore();
var addOrder = ref.collection("ActiveTrades").doc(userId).collection("orders").add({
 orderId: 1234
}).then(response => {
  console.log("The new order ID is", response.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As for getting a uid auto-generated just call `.doc()` empty [like](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data):

> ```
> // Add a new document with a generated id.
> var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();
>
> // later...
> newCityRef.set(data);
> ```

Review your Firestore database in the online Firebase Web Console. Notice the options available. ActiveTrades is a *collection* of *documents*. *Documents* can have *fields* or sub *collection*s. While [this is documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), it's easiest (for me anyways) to visually see it.

So, try and avoid thinking of "paths" as this isn't XML/XPath and it's not even precisely JSON - it's Firestore.

You can get at a location with .collection("collName").doc("docName)...
and you can get at it with the "collName/docName" shorthand too I believe.

[image]